# GStreamer images to video

Tags: gstreamer

I have 4 png with different resolutions (1920x1080, 1280x720, 1920x1200) and I try to convert them to a video slideshow.

This pipeline works:

```
 gst-launch-1.0.exe -e multifilesrc location="multi_img_%d.png" index=0 caps="image/png,framerate=(fraction)1/2,width=1920,height=1080" ! pngdec ! videoconvert  ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080  ! autovideosink
```

while when I try to force framerate it only reads the first image.

I tried :

```
 gst-launch-1.0.exe -e multifilesrc location="multi_img_%d.png" index=0 caps="image/png,framerate=(fraction)1/2,width=1920,height=1080" ! pngdec ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080 ! videorate ! video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=25/1 ! autovideosink
```

and

```
 gst-launch-1.0.exe -e multifilesrc location="multi_img_%d.png" index=0 caps="image/png,framerate=(fraction)1/2,width=854,height=480" ! pngdec ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! videorate ! video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=25/1 ! autovideosink
```

I don't understand why adding framerate would cause my pipeline to ignore some pictures.
(I am under Windows 10 with the brand new GStreamer 1.14.0)

EDIT: I forgot to tell that when I manually resize my picture so they have all the same resolution, all the above pipelines work!

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it is a timing issue. You are running a real-time pipeline, but most likely the PNG decoding is not fast enough to deliver frames in a 25/1 fps manner and the videosink drops them has they arrive too late. Maybe adding `max-lateness=-1` to the videosink prevents the dropping of frames in your case.